# Mysql - Sum total from subqueries using group by

Tags: sql, subquery

People help me please,

i have theses selects in the same table that only thing is diferent on this selects is "b.status=x":

```
SELECT c.name as technician,COUNT(a.tickets_id) AS total
FROM glpi_tickets_users a 
JOIN glpi_tickets b ON a.tickets_id = b.id 
JOIN glpi_users c ON a.users_id = c.id 
WHERE a.type=2 AND b.status=2 
GROUP BY a.users_id 
ORDER by total DESC;

SELECT c.name as technician,COUNT(a.tickets_id) AS total 
FROM glpi_tickets_users a 
JOIN glpi_tickets b ON a.tickets_id = b.id 
JOIN glpi_users c ON a.users_id = c.id 
WHERE a.type=2 AND b.status=5 
GROUP BY a.users_id 
ORDER by total DESC

SELECT c.name as technician,COUNT(a.tickets_id) AS total 
FROM glpi_tickets_users a 
JOIN glpi_tickets b ON a.tickets_id = b.id 
JOIN glpi_users c ON a.users_id = c.id 
WHERE a.type=2 AND b.status=6 
GROUP BY a.users_id 
ORDER by total DESC;
```

so i want to sum total of tickets of theses technician grouping by technician and sorting by total desc.

obs: each select returns diferent group of technicians

how can i do this ? tks very much

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: So what do the above queries return?

Comment: could you give the database schema. And then the question

Comment: i want to recovery the total produced tickets per user in these tree diferent stats. like: technician - status 2 - status 5 - status 6.

Comment: Anybody? it´s just like this : NAME | PROCESSING | SOLVED | CLOSED | TOTAL